# How to restrict to input time for edittext in android

Tags: java, android, validation, android-edittext

I have to allow user to input only time in ##:## format in edit text on the fly, is there any way to achieve it? I have used below code but it doest not working.

I able to enter number more than 24 value like 45623:5689.

```
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_TIME)
```

Even `android:text="time"` is also not working.

how can i achieve this thing. Can anybody suggest me how can i do this thing.

I want to allow user to enter in first 2 places up to 23 value and then compulasary : and then user can allow up to 59 value.

for example

```
23:59 correct
24:05 incorrect
02:56 correct
02:79 incorrect
```

I used this customize filter also but its not working

I got this code from some where else in SO.

**Code:**

```
    InputFilter timeFilter = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest,
                int dstart, int dend) {
            if (source.length() == 0) {
                return null;// deleting, keep original editing
            }
            String result = "";
            result += dest.toString().substring(0, dstart);
            result += source.toString().substring(start, end);
            result += dest.toString().substring(dend, dest.length());

            if (result.length() > 5) {
                return "";// do not allow this edit
            }
            boolean allowEdit = true;
            char c;
            if (result.length() > 0) {
                c = result.charAt(0);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '2');
            }
            if (result.length() > 1) {
                c = result.charAt(1);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
            }
            if (result.length() > 2) {
                c = result.charAt(2);
                allowEdit &= (c == ':');
            }
            if (result.length() > 3) {
                c = result.charAt(3);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '5');
            }
            if (result.length() > 4) {
                c = result.charAt(4);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
            }
            return allowEdit ? null : "";
        }
    };
```

**Edited Question : main.xml file code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRecipientName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="@string/recipient_name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edTxtRecipient"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtParcelDeliverTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="@string/delivered_time" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edTxtParcelDeliverTime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRecipient_OK"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@android:string/ok" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This code is working but if i insert first alphabet and insert proper value then its not working because `source` contains its previous character value.

Comment: I tried your code just now, I think the problem in XML file that i had mention yesterday, Remove any Input type validation from XML of EditText of your Activity and then it works fine

Comment: Thanks for help wait i will put my XML file code. There is no validation or no inputtype validation.

Comment: Ya I got the problem. That is because of predictive texting in android. That's a keyboard setting you have to disable it from settings. In emulator goto Settings => Langugage & Keyboard settings => Android keyboard and uncheck Quick Fixes for some live devices like HTC Desire goto Menu => Settings => Language & Keyboard => Touch Input => Text Input => Untick Prediction These may change as per modifications made by the companies

Comment: @GirishNair Problem is different i checked with my current Jelly bean emulator but its not working. facing same problem as like before sequence

Comment: Please do debug then u will know problem occures when we press alphabet first and then press correct key variable source contains its previous alphabet character also. Actually in other case it deleted from there. but in this its not deleted from there

Comment: Hey sam Now check the updated answer(EDIT 2)...

Comment: @GirishNair Had a change any thing in Code

Comment: Ya I did change the filter code you can review it

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the chars to ints, then test if they are greater than 24 and 60.

```
int a = ((int) result.charAt(0)) - 48;
int b = ((int) result.charAt(1)) - 48;
int c = ((int) result.charAt(3)) - 48;
if(a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0) {
    Not right.
}

if((a > 2 || (a == 2 && b > 3)) || c > 59) {
    Neither is this.
}
```

Minus 48 because numbers 0 is 48th in the ascii table. **The test has to be ascii.**

Comment: My customize filter is working but its not working if i enter first alphabet then numbers.

Comment: Surely then the length if sorts that out?

Comment: So if you enter alphabet like this: ab:cd , then it lets it through?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of char why dont you use string, Because char can also be used for comparsion as it can return numbers

```
char c ='a';
    if(c>10)
    //do something

    //OR
int x = c;
```

So why dont you use String instead of char

or what you can do is, take 1st two chars using substring or something like that and use Integer.parse() method to parse it, if it successfully parsed then its a valid number else it is not so you can validate it and similarly do it for next two chars

***EDIT***

If you wanted to implement like this 
    23:59 correct
    24:05 incorrect
    02:56 correct
    02:79 incorrect

Then here is the code that worked from my side

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 InputFilter timeFilter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timeFilter  = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest,
                int dstart, int dend) {
            if (source.length() == 0) {
                return null;// deleting, keep original editing
            }
            String result = "";
            result += dest.toString().substring(0, dstart);
            result += source.toString().substring(start, end);
            result += dest.toString().substring(dend, dest.length());

            if (result.length() > 5) {
                return "";// do not allow this edit
            }
            boolean allowEdit = true;
            char c;
            if (result.length() > 0) {
                c = result.charAt(0);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '2');
            }
            if (result.length() > 1) {
                c = result.charAt(1);
                if(result.charAt(0) == '0' || result.charAt(0) == '1')
                    allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
                else
                    allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '3');
            }
            if (result.length() > 2) {
                c = result.charAt(2);
                allowEdit &= (c == ':');
            }
            if (result.length() > 3) {
                c = result.charAt(3);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '5');
            }
            if (result.length() > 4) {
                c = result.charAt(4);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
            }
            return allowEdit ? null : "";
        }

    };

    EditText txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edTxtParcelDeliverTime);
    txt1.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{timeFilter});
}
}
```

I have just taken your XML and placed as my mains layout
AND there are no changes to XML
Now try this and tell ?

***EDIT 2***
Now here i have added a validtion for firs char check using doneOnce boolean value
This works now, tell me if you have any other problem from this code now

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText edt1;
InputFilter timeFilter;
private String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";
private boolean doneOnce = false;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timeFilter  = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest,
                int dstart, int dend) {

            if(source.length() > 1 && doneOnce == false){
                source = source.subSequence(source.length()-1, source.length());
                if(source.charAt(0)  >= '0' && source.charAt(0) <= '2'){
                    doneOnce = true;
                    return source;
                }else{
                    return "";
                }
            }


            if (source.length() == 0) {
                return null;// deleting, keep original editing
            }
            String result = "";
            result += dest.toString().substring(0, dstart);
            result += source.toString().substring(start, end);
            result += dest.toString().substring(dend, dest.length());

            if (result.length() > 5) {
                return "";// do not allow this edit
            }
            boolean allowEdit = true;
            char c;
            if (result.length() > 0) {
                c = result.charAt(0);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '2');
            }
            if (result.length() > 1) {
                c = result.charAt(1);
                if(result.charAt(0) == '0' || result.charAt(0) == '1')
                    allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
                else
                    allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '3');
            }
            if (result.length() > 2) {
                c = result.charAt(2);
                allowEdit &= (c == ':');
            }
            if (result.length() > 3) {
                c = result.charAt(3);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '5');
            }
            if (result.length() > 4) {
                c = result.charAt(4);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
            }
            return allowEdit ? null : "";
        }

    };


    edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edTxtParcelDeliverTime);
    edt1.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { timeFilter });

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My this code is not working when i enter alphabet or '-' symbol in between. if i entered other symbols then its working fine. Why in my filter source contains previous value instead of delete that invalid character.

Comment: In you XML for EditText try removing android:inputType="number" or anything like that and then re-validate your code, may be its being filter by the android system itself so try removing any such item if present

Comment: Thanks for answer. but in your working application try this  : first enter `'q'` character and then `'t'` character and then try to enter `12` and then try to enter any alphabet. in this case its not working. if i entered first `digits` then its working fine.

Comment: Its not working Try this character sequence in delivered time.

Comment: I think you are able to get my actual problem

Comment: Ya I got the problem. That is because of predictive texting in android. That's a keyboard setting you have to disable it from settings.

In emulator goto Settings => Langugage & Keyboard settings => Android keyboard  and uncheck Quick Fixes

for some live devices like HTC Desire
goto Menu => Settings => Language & Keyboard => Touch Input => Text Input => Untick Prediction

These may change as per modifications made by the companies

Comment: Ohhh.. Thanks man for your answer. Can i do any soultion for this??

Comment: I dont think you can do anything, Thats a user defined setting :(

Comment: Its working, when i enter qwe12345 only 12 is printed (as per your need)and then only : is allowed and so on...

Comment: Here this same code is not working for me. Have you enale prediction text or any thing property set in android layout xml file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18854/discussion-between-girish-nair-and-sam-k)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I simply edited the code you provided....

```
InputFilter[] timeFilter = new InputFilter[1];

timeFilter[0] = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        if (source.length() == 0) {
            return null;// deleting, keep original editing
        }

        String result = "";
        result += dest.toString().substring(0, dstart);
        result += source.toString().substring(start, end);
        result += dest.toString().substring(dend, dest.length());

        if (result.length() > 5) {
            return "";// do not allow this edit
        }

        boolean allowEdit = true;
        char c;
        if (result.length() > 0) {
            c = result.charAt(0);
            allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '2' && !(Character.isLetter(c)));
        }

        if (result.length() > 1) {
            c = result.charAt(1);
            allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9' && !(Character.isLetter(c)));
        }

        if (result.length() > 2) {
            c = result.charAt(2);
            allowEdit &= (c == ':'&&!(Character.isLetter(c)));
        }

        if (result.length() > 3) {
            c = result.charAt(3);
            allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '5' && !(Character.isLetter(c)));
        }

        if (result.length() > 4) {
            c = result.charAt(4);
            allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9'&& !(Character.isLetter(c)));
        }

        return allowEdit ? null : "";
    }
};
```

This works absolutely fine for me. Accepts time in format `hh:mm` only (no other character accepted)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this library](https://github.com/PaoloConte/time-edit-text) for time `EditText`. 
The code is easy to use. I add some explanations from the code owner:

> A custom EditText (actually derived from TextView) to input
>   time in 24h format.
>   Features:
>   - It always shows the currently set time, so it's never empty.
>
> - Both virtual and physical keyboards can be used.
> - The current digit is highlighted;
> - when a number on the keyboard is pressed, the digit is replaced.
> - Back key moves the cursor backward.
> - Space key moves the cursor
>     forward.

Here is the `TimeEditText` Class:

```
public class TimeEditText extends TextView {

private static final int POSITION_NONE = -1;

private int[] digits = new int[4];
private int currentPosition = POSITION_NONE;
private int mImeOptions;

public TimeEditText(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public TimeEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TimeEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    if (attrs != null && !isInEditMode()) {
        mImeOptions = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "imeOptions", 0);
    }

    updateText();       
}

/**
 * @return the current hour (from 0 to 23)
 */
public int getHour() {
    return digits[0]*10+digits[1];
}

/**
 * @return the current minute
 */
public int getMinutes() {
    return digits[2]*10+digits[3];
}

/**
 * Set the current hour
 * @param hour hour (from 0 to 23)
 */
public void setHour(int hour) {
    hour = hour % 24;
    digits[0] = hour/10;
    digits[1] = hour%10;
    updateText();
}

/**
 * Set the current minute
 * @param min minutes (from 0 to 59)
 */
public void setMinutes(int min) {
    min = min % 60;
    digits[2] = min/10;
    digits[3] = min%10;
    updateText();
}

@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    // hide cursor if not focused
    currentPosition = focused ? 0 : POSITION_NONE;
    updateText();
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
}   

private void updateText() {
    int bold = currentPosition > 1 ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition;   
    int color = getTextColors().getDefaultColor();
    Spannable text = new SpannableString(String.format("%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinutes()));
    if (bold >= 0) {
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color & 0xFFFFFF | 0xA0000000), 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), bold, bold+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), bold, bold+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        text.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0x40808080), bold, bold+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    setText(text);  
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        requestFocusFromTouch();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(this,0);
        if (currentPosition == POSITION_NONE) {
            currentPosition = 0;
            updateText();
        }
    }
    return true;
}   

private boolean onKeyEvent(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event != null && event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        return false;

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {  
        // moves cursor backward
        currentPosition = currentPosition >= 0 ? (currentPosition+3)%4 : 3;
        updateText();
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
        // moves cursor forward
        currentPosition = (currentPosition+1)%4;
        updateText();
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        View v = focusSearch(FOCUS_DOWN);
        boolean next = v!=null;
        if (next) {
            next = v.requestFocus(FOCUS_DOWN);
        }         
        if (!next) {
            hideKeyboard();
            currentPosition = POSITION_NONE;
            updateText();
        }
        return true;
    }       

    char c = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();  
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        currentPosition = currentPosition == POSITION_NONE ? 0 : currentPosition;
        int n = c - '0';
        boolean valid = false;

        switch (currentPosition) {
            case 0: // first hour digit must be 0-2
                valid = n <= 2;
                break;
            case 1: // second hour digit must be 0-3 if first digit is 2
                valid = digits[0] < 2 || n <= 3;
                break;
            case 2: // first minute digit must be 0-6
                valid = n < 6;
                break;
            case 3: // second minuti digit always valid (0-9)
                valid = true;
                break;
        }

        if (valid) {
            if (currentPosition == 0 && n == 2 && digits[1] > 3) { // clip to 23 hours max
                digits[1] = 3;
            }

            digits[currentPosition] = n;
            currentPosition = currentPosition < 3 ? currentPosition+1 : POSITION_NONE;  // if it is the last digit, hide cursor
            updateText();
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);        
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
    // events from physical keyboard
    return onKeyEvent(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    // manage events from the virtual keyboard
    outAttrs.actionLabel = null;
    outAttrs.label = "time";
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
    outAttrs.imeOptions = mImeOptions | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI;

    if ((outAttrs.imeOptions & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION) == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED) {
        if (focusSearch(FOCUS_DOWN) != null) {
            outAttrs.imeOptions |= EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT;
        } else {
            outAttrs.imeOptions |= EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE;
        }
    }

    return new BaseInputConnection(this, false) {
        @Override
        public boolean performEditorAction(int actionCode) {
            if (actionCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                hideKeyboard();
                currentPosition = POSITION_NONE;
                updateText();
            } else if (actionCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT){
                View v = focusSearch(FOCUS_DOWN);
                if (v!=null) {
                    v.requestFocus(FOCUS_DOWN);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {
            onKeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, null); 
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            onKeyEvent(event.getKeyCode(), event);
            return true;
        }           
     };
 }
}
```

You must add this lines to your view:

```
<YourPackageName.TimeEditText
            android:id="@+id/satOpenEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

//THis handles the input for the date and time at the runtime and all the //invalid atttempt are automatically consumed
//this is an alternative to regex expression that you can implement

```
//using the input regulation for the time data
    timeField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        String beforeTXT;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                Log.i("before TEXT TEXXT", " this : "+s+" and "+start+" and "+count+"and "+after);
                beforeTXT= ""+s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int input ;

            //first determine whether user is at hrs side or min side
            if (s.toString().equals("")){
                return;
            }
            if(s.toString().length()>2 && start<=2){ //means the user is at hour side
                input = Integer.parseInt(s.toString().substring(0,1)) % 10;

            }
            else if(s.toString().length()>2 && start>=3) {//means that user is at min side
                input = Integer.parseInt("0"+s.toString().substring(3))%10;

            }
            else if(s.toString().indexOf(":")==1){ // if we have for eg 1: or 0: then we take first character for parsing
                input = Integer.parseInt(s.toString().charAt(0)+"");
            }
            else{ //else it is default where the user is at first position
                input = Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) % 10;
            }

            //Special case where 00: is autommatically converted to 12: in 12hr time format
            if(s.toString().contains("00:")){
                Log.i("INsisde )))","i am called ");
                timeField.setText("12:");
               return;
            }

            //Now we manipulate the input and its formattin and cursor movement
            if(input<=1 && start ==0){ //thiis is for first input value to check .... time shouldnt exceed 12 hr
                //do nothing
            }
            else if (input>1 && start==0){ //if at hour >1 is press then automaticc set the time as 02: or 05: etc
             timeField.setText("0"+s+":");
            }
            else if(input>2 && start==1 && !s.toString().startsWith("0")){ //whe dont have greater than 12 hrs so second postionn shouldn't exceed value 2
                timeField.setText(beforeTXT);
            }
            else if(start==1 && !beforeTXT.contains(":")){  //if valid input 10 or 11 or 12 is given then convert it to 10: 11: or 12:
                timeField.setText(s.toString()+":");

                if(s.toString().length()==1 && s.toString().startsWith("0")){
                timeField.setText("");
                }
                if(s.toString().startsWith("1")&& s.toString().length()==1){ //on back space convert 1: to 01:
                    timeField.setText("0"+timeField.getText().toString());
                }

           }
            else if(start == 3 && input >5 ){ //min fig shouldn't exceed 59 so ...if at first digit of min input >5 then do nothing or codpy the earlier text
                timeField.setText(beforeTXT);
            }
           else if (start>4 && s.toString().length()>5){ // the total string lenght shouldn't excced 5
                timeField.setText(beforeTXT);
            }
            else if(start<2 && beforeTXT.length()>2){
                timeField.setText(beforeTXT);

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Log.i("after  TEXT TEXXT", " this : "+s);
            timeField.setSelection(timeField.getText().toString().length());

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating custom pattern

```
    //handles time 20:00 - 23:59 
    TIMEUP = Pattern.compile("(" +
            "[2]{1}" + "[0-3]{1}" +
            "\\:" +
            "[0-5]{1}" + "[0-9]{1}" +
            ")");

    //handles time 00:00 - 19:59 
    TIMEDOWN = Pattern.compile("(" +
            "[0-1]{0,1}" + "[0-9]{1}" +
            "\\:" +
            "[0-5]{1}" + "[0-9]{1}" +
            ")");
```

And then use it to check if the string matches one of the patterns, if it doesn't you can use for example TextInputLayout where you can display an error message

```
if (TIMEUP.matcher(time).matches() || TIMEDOWN.matcher(time).matches()){
    //if true.. your code here
} else {
    inputlayout.setError("Invalid time format");
}
```