# How do I add a time-input EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making a Scoreboard app, and I want the user to be able to input a time. I'd like it so that it starts at 0:00, then when the user enters "1" into the field it reads "0:01," then when they enter "1" again it reads, "0:11," and when they enter "1" again it reads "1:11," etc. How could I do that, with the colon staying in the same place? I didn't see anything built into Android Studio for it, so maybe an easy algorithm to use editText.setText() after determining how many digits there are?

Comment: This question may have the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120947/how-to-restrict-to-input-time-for-edittext-in-android

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate: the linked question is about validation, whereas this is a question of edit field behaviour as characters are entered.

Comment: Wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it guided me in the right direction. Thanks.